# Specific help with Xcode Project Template that is not doing substitution in file contents

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

We are trying to make a project template, but the documentation on this is spotty or non-existent.

Doing some reverse-engineering on some template files, we have come up with the following.  However, it doen't actually work!

First of all, we have figured out that project templates should be installed inside:

~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates

We have made project  and installed it here, and this part works - we see this show up in the "User Templates" section of the Xcode "New Project" chooser.

The project folder contains the following files.  As you can see, I want the file names to be subsituted (that part works) but as you will see, I also want the contents of the files to be substituted; this doesn't happen.

- ___PROJECTNAME___.xcodeproj
- ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER____Prefix.pch
- ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___.icns
- ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Delegate.h
- ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Delegate.m
- ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Template.html
- Debug.xcconfig
- en.lproj
- Info.plist
- Release.xcconfig

I have put in two special files into the ___PROJECTNAME___.xcodeproj package:

- TemplateInfo.plist
- TemplateIcon.icns - the icon to show up in the New Project window

If I create a new project (called "Foo & Bar" as a stress test) using this template, these are the files it creates:

- Debug.xcconfig
- en.lproj
- Foo & Bar.xcodeproj
- Foo___Bar_Prefix.pch
- Foo___Bar.icns
- Foo___BarDelegate.h
- Foo___BarDelegate.m
- Foo___BarTemplate.html
- Info.plist
- Release.xcconfig

So far so good!

But looking in the file contents, I get things like this.  Here is the contents of Foo___BarDelegate.m:

```
//
//  «PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.m
//  «PROJECTNAME»
//
//  Created by «FULLUSERNAME» on «DATE».
//  Copyright «ORGANIZATIONNAME» «YEAR» . All rights reserved.
//

#import "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.h"


@implementation «PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate

@end
```

The apparent issue is that somehow I'm doing the TemplateInfo.plist wrong.  But then again, notice how not only are my special items not being substitued, but the standard items don't even get replaced!  So maybe it's a deeper issue.

But with a problematic TemplateInfo.plist being my best hypothesis, I present a couple of variations I have tried.  Neither work.

Either:

```
{
    FilesToMacroExpand = (
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_\_Prefix.pch",
        "en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings",
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_\_Prefix.pch",
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_.icns",
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_Delegate.h",
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_Delegate.m",
        "\_\_\_PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER\_\_\_Template.html",
        "Info.plist"
    );
    Description = "This project builds a cocoa-based \"element\" plugin for Sandvox.";
}
```

or:

```
{
    FilesToMacroExpand = (
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»\_Prefix.pch",
        "en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings",
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»\_Prefix.pch",
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER».icns",
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.h",
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.m",
        "«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Template.html",
        "Info.plist"
    );
    Description = "This project builds a cocoa-based \"element\" plugin for Sandvox.";
}
```

**Update**: I've also tried adding the "FilesToRename" key, even though the ___ seems to be automatically causing renaming to happen.  This is the plist contents with that in, in XML format (since some people were worried about that UTF-8 nature of things -- yes, it's a valid plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>This project builds a cocoa-based "element" plugin for Sandvox.</string>
    <key>FilesToMacroExpand</key>
    <array>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»_Prefix.pch</string>
        <string>en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings</string>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER».icns</string>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.h</string>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.m</string>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Template.html</string>
        <string>Info.plist</string>
    </array>
    <key>FilesToRename</key>
    <dict>
        <key>___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___.icns</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER».icns</string>
        <key>___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Delegate.h</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.h</string>
        <key>___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Delegate.m</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Delegate.m</string>
        <key>___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___Template.html</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Template.html</string>
        <key>___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER____Prefix.pch</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»_Prefix.pch</string>
        <key>___PROJECTNAME___.xcodeproj</key>
        <string>«PROJECTNAME».xcodeproj</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: danwood, please do append any of your own future tips on this question as you continue to discover them.  Your posting of this question has re-inspired me to try this myself and I would love to hear what you finally conclude once it all works.

Answer (score 4):

You likely want to use a "FilesToRename" section.   The following is from the PyObjC Cocoa Document Based Application template.  It works fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>This project builds a Cocoa-based application written in Python that uses the NSDocument architecture.</string>
        <key>FilesToMacroExpand</key>
        <array>
                <string>«PROJECTNAME»_Prefix.pch</string>
                <string>Info.plist</string>
                <string>English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings</string>
                <string>English.lproj/MainMenu.xib</string>
                <string>English.lproj/«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Document.xib</string>
                <string>main.py</string>
                <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Document.py</string>
                <string>main.m</string>
        </array>
        <key>FilesToRename</key>
        <dict>
                <key>CocoaAppDocument.py</key>
                <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Document.py</string>
                <key>CocoaDocApp_Prefix.pch</key>
                <string>«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»_Prefix.pch</string>
                <key>English.lproj/CocoaAppDocument.xib</key>
                <string>English.lproj/«PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER»Document.xib</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: My files seem to be getting renamed automatically; I think it's the contents inside that are not being handled.

Answer (score 4):

Another resource is Jesse Grosjean's [XcodeTemplateFactory](http://hogbaysoftware.com/products/xcodetemplatefactory). It's free and open source and may save you future headaches.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Found the project at http://groups.google.com/group/hogbaysoftware/browse_thread/thread/f8a56455ec1a4e72?pli=1

Answer (score 3):

Further to Chris' answer ("There are two styles of templates..."), you can find examples of the new style in the templates for another platform...

The following excerpt shows examples of a few typical substitution variables using triple underbars; if you use these in place of the guillamot-based variables in your Foo___BarDelegate.m, it should work.

```
//
//  ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___AppDelegate.m
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___ ___YEAR___. All rights reserved.
//

#import "___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___AppDelegate
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two styles of templates, distinguished by the template macro delimiters: old-style uses MacRoman guillamots in a UTF-8 file, and the new style uses triple underbars throughout.  You can't mix and match.  The new style is for 3.1 and later only, and you must use the triple underbars in the file names to be substituted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you missing those "<<" like symbols? Thats the reason why `xcode` is not recognizing and replacing template tags..

Answer (score 0):

I was just bangin my head on same problem!

For me, adding files in plist works, I changed html file with php file and it is parsed. 
But now it does parse only few first items from list. 
Old html file is still: «PROJECTNAME»
Like this program does not count how many items there is in a list...

But where is the place in code, where it doesn't do that... ?